# Swap values in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here's a Find-Replace which swaps values:

```
Find: right\|left
Repl: \,(if (equal "right" \&) "left" "right")
```

Here's an attempt to convert it into interactive function:

```
(defun swaps (rit lft)
  "Swaps rit to lft."
  (interactive "sChange this: 
sTo this: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (region-beginning))
    (while (search-forward-regexp ("%s\\|%s" rit lft) nil t) 
      (replace-match (if (equal rit \\&) lft rit) t nil))))
```

I also tried `rit\\|lft` and `rit\|lft` instead of `("%s\\|%s" rit lft)`...

**Edit**:

The answer is:

```
(defun swaps (rit lft)
  "Swaps rit to lft."
  (interactive "sChange this: 
sTo this: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (region-beginning))
    (while  (search-forward-regexp (format "%s\\|%s" 
                                          (regexp-quote rit)
                                          (regexp-quote lft)) (region-end) t) 
      (replace-match (if (equal rit (match-string 0)) lft rit) t nil))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`("%s\\|%s" rit lft)` isn't a valid Lisp expression: when it's evaluated Emacs will complain that `"%s\\|%s"` isn't a function. You probably want to do

```
 (format "%s\\|%s" rit lft)
```

and it would be better to use `regexp-quote` in case your strings contain regexp special characters:

```
(format "%s\\|%s" 
        (regexp-quote rit)
        (regexp-quote lft))
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `regexp-opt` function, which constructs an efficient regexp to match any one of a list of strings:

```
(regexp-opt (list rit lft))
```

`\\&` only represents the matched string within a replacement argument to `replace-regexp`, `replace-match` and similar functions. In other Lisp code you need to use `(match-string 0)`.

Finally, if you only want this to work on the region you should probably supply `(region-end)` as the second argument to `search-forward-regexp`.